# Getting error while running apksigner verify

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, build.gradle, ionic4

I'm currently using ionic framework java version **1.8.0_261** while running **apksigner verify** getting java runtime class file version issue. I have attached error image.Please give m a solution for this.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to updgrade your JRE to version 9 at least
Or use an older version of the apksigner ( but I would not go that way )

Comment: JRE version 9 not support for zipalign. how to check apk signer version?

Comment: "apksigner version"
which zipalign is used ? Mine is in the same directory as apksigner , build tools version is 30.0.2

Comment: I'm using 30.0.0 only, while i'm checking with JRE version 9 it's showing no signature like that